# Python SQLAlchemy response type to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

When I run a SQLAlchemy query to get values from a SQLAlchemy.String() column;

```py
query = db.session.query(self.hosts_class.cluster.distinct())

    for row in query.all()
```

Iterating and printing the result object results in output like;
`('sometext',)`

If I browse the row object I can see that row contains a key, value pair of "0": "sometext".  What's the correct way to access this value from row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is a single-element tuple, so you could access by index:

```
for row in query:
    print(row[0])
```

or by unpacking the tuple

```
for row, in query:  # <- note the comma
    print(row)
```